# Crash's trying to find view

Tags: java, android

I have a slight problem that I have been stuck on. I have narrowed it down and it seems that my application is crashing on create when i am trying to find a text view. I do not understand why, maybe i have been looking at this to long and dont see the obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```js
public class FinalActivity extends Activity {

    EditText fullName;
    EditText serialNumber;
    EditText numberOfTicket;
    EditText fullCost;
    EditText discount;
    EditText totalCostOfTickets;
    EditText dinnerYesNo;
    EditText numberForDinner;
    EditText dinnerCost;
    EditText vatTv;
    EditText totalCost;
 
    SharedPreferences thePrefs;// Shared preferences variable
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;// New editor to add to shared preferences
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

 thePrefs = getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.FIRSTTIMEPREFS, 0);
 editor = thePrefs.edit();
  
 fullName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.personsNameTv);
 /*serialNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.serialNumberTv);
 numberOfTicket = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberOfTicketTv);
 fullCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullCostBeforeTv);
 discount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.discountAmountTV);
 totalCostOfTickets = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalTicketCostEt);
 dinnerYesNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dinnerAvailedTv);
 numberForDinner = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberForDinnerTv);
 dinnerCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dinnerCostTv);
 vatTv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vatTv);
 totalCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalCostTv);*/
  
  
 //fullName.setText (thePrefs.getString(PersonalInfoActivity.FULLNAME, ""));
   
    }
}
```

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#404040"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/ticketSummary"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promptTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/confirmCorrectDetails"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/redborder" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/personsNameTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fullName"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serialNumberTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/personsNameTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/serialNumber"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfTicketTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/serialNumberTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/numberOfTickets"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullCostBeforeTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/numberOfTicketTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/fullCostBeforeDiscount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discountAmountTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fullCostBeforeTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/amountOfDisount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalTicketCostEt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/discountAmountTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/totalTicketCost"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dinnerAvailedTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/totalTicketCostEt"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dinnerAvailed"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberForDinnerTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dinnerAvailedTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/numberForDinner"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dinnerCostTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/numberForDinnerTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dinnerCost"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vatTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dinnerCostTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/vat"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalCostTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vatTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/totalCost"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirmBtn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:onClick="confirmTicketOptions"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your crash log. @user3478232

Comment: There are no `Edittext` in your layout. All are Textviews. @user3478232

Comment: It should be `Textview fullName ;` and `fullName = (Textview )findViewById(R.id.personsNameTv);` @user3478232

Comment: Omg Im such and idiot. I have spent to much time on this project. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML you are using Text-view and in java file you define it Edit-text

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/personsNameTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fullName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Replace with

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personsNameTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fullName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: Omg Im such and idiot. I have spent to much time on this project. Thanks very much

Comment: @user3478232...Its ok... It happen, because we r human beings... :) You can up-vote, if my answer helped you.

Comment: I do not have the reputation yet other wise i would.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible things possible. Either you want all `Textviews` or all `EditText`.

1. If you want all `Textview` then replace all your `EditText`in java file with `Textview`.

   ```
   Textview fullName;
   fullName = (Textview )findViewById(R.id.personsNameTv);
   ```
2. If you want all `EditText` then replace all `Textview` in xml with `EditText`.

   ```
    <EditText
           android:id="@+id/personsNameTv" 
           .../>
   ```

Comment: Welcome. @user3478232 accept the answer which you find more helpful. So this question will be out of unanswered questions. Also you can upvote it.